# WCF: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via when i call IInternal proxy = factory.CreateChannel(); on Client

Tags: c#, wcf

Server's App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Server.InternalClass" behaviorConfiguration="NewBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="IInternal" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="Common.IInternal">
          <identity>
            <dns value="MyMachine"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://MyMachine:8733/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

Client

```
static ChannelFactory<IInternal> factory = new ChannelFactory<IInternal>(new WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("https://MyMachine:8733/IInternal"));
```

When i call the method  factory.CreateChannel(), i get error

I configure certificate

[image]

Comment: Does the service start up correctly? What configuration do you have for the client in the app.config of the client?

Comment: Service start up correctly. I don't have config file for the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to tell the client to use a secure transport channel so that it uses https instead of http. This is true because the binding settings at the client must match the ones at the service side.

You can do this via configuration in the app.config file of the client, or you can do it via code like this:

```
var ws_http_binding = new WSHttpBinding();

ws_http_binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

ChannelFactory<IInternal> factory = 
    new ChannelFactory<IInternal>(
        ws_http_binding,
        new EndpointAddress("https://MyMachine:8733/IInternal"));

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```